# Как определить, какого типа объект хранится в свойстве, типа TObject, другого объекта

Tags: delphi

Есть объект `type Tmain = class`, у которого есть свойство `property myObject: TObject read FmyObject;`. Есть еще несколько объектов `type TA = class`, `type TB = class`...

В различных ситуациях, я присваиваю свойству myObject, то TA, то TB.
Если знать, какой именно объект храниться в свойстве, к нему можно обратиться (myObject as TA). А как быть если я не знаю, как узнать какой тип храниться в свойстве, не используя IS, если возможною

UPD

Избежать IS хочу потому что типов боле 50, у каждого есть функция под названием DoPlay, но код внутри разный

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает `is`?

Comment: @zed более 50 типов сравнивать придется

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если у каждого объекта есть функция `DoPlay`, то эту функцию вам надо вынести в родительский класс или в отдельный интерфейс и сменить тип `myObject` на базовый. Тогда вам будет абсолютно без разницы, какой конкретно объект был присвоен `myObject`, ведь в любом случае, у него будет нужная вам функция и вы можете её вызывать без приведений типов через `as`.

Объявляете базовый класс с абстрактным методом (метод, который должен быть реализован в классах-наследниках):

```
ТMyBaseObj = class(TObject)
public
  procedure DoPlay(...); virtual; abstract;
end;
```

Создаёте наследников и в каждом реализуете свою логику для метода `DoPlay`:

```
TA = class(ТMyBaseObj)
public
  procedure DoPlay(...); override;
end;

procedure TA.DoPlay(...);
begin
  // реализация метода для класса A
end;

TB = class(ТMyBaseObj)
public
  procedure DoPlay(...); override;
end;

procedure TB.DoPlay(...);
begin
  // реализация метода для класса B
end;
```

Объявляете свою переменную `myObject` как `ТMyBaseObj` и в нужном месте просто вызываете функцию `DoPlay`, абстрагируясь от конкретной реализации:

```
TMain = class(TObject)
  FMyObject: ТMyBaseObj;
  procedure DoPlay(..);
end;

procedure TMain.DoPlay(..);
begin
  // вызов функции 
  FMyObject.DoPlay(..);
end;
```

Comment: я не совсем понял последний пункт по поводу вызова. У меня на практике `TGamePlatform = class(TObject) FGame: TBaseGame;`, `TBaseGame = class(TObject) function DoPlay(): virtual;`, TGameA = class(TBaseGame) function DoPlay(); override;`

Comment: если я допишу Abstract, то вызвав FGame.DoPlay выполнится код тот что в потомке TBaseGame, не зависимо от того какой из потомков в нем хранится?

Comment: `Abstract` означает, что в базовом классе реализация отсутствует и наследники **обязаны** его реализовывать. Если метод просто `virtual` то вам в базовом классе надо писать хоть какую реализацию этого метода, пусть даже пустую функцию, а у наследников **нету обязанности** реализовывать этот метод. И если вы вдруг забудете реализовать этот метод у наследника, то в первом случае (с abstract) программа не скомпилируется, а во втором - скомпилируется и будет вызываться пустой базовый метод. Т.е. вы защищаетесь от ошибок и при вызове `DoPlay` у вас гарантированно будет вызываться метод наследника.

Comment: А я читал и не понимал для чего abstract, даже вопрос по нему написать хотел. спасибо. одно уточнение, если я используя abstract впишу в функцию то что в начале должны делать и наследники и впишу у наследников inhereted, код предка выполнится, а потом код потомка?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 С `abstract` вы не можете вписать общий код в базовый класс. В этом и суть - у предка нету кода для этого метода. Ему **запрещено** его иметь. И `inherited` (*унаследованный*) метод в данном случае отсутствует. Если вам нужен общий код и без `inherited` никак, то `abstract` метод вам не подходит. В этом случае, надо внимательно следить, чтобы у всех ваших 50-ти потомков была реализация `DoPlay`, чтобы вызывались именно методы наследников.

Comment: inherited не обязательна, просто хотел немного сократить код. "внимательно следить, чтобы у всех ваших 50-ти потомков была реализация DoPlay" можно и без abstract если функция будет во всех потомках?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 Да, можно. При вызове методов вначале происходит поиск у наследника, если у него метода нет, то ищется у предка.

Comment: Если DoPlay у предка просто virtual, и такая функция точно будет у всех наследников, я создам игру(FGame: TBaseGame;) так  GamePlatform.Fgame := TGameA.Create; а потом напишу 
не (GamePlatform.Fgame as TGameA).DoPlay, а GamePlatform.Fgame.DoPlay, то все равно вызовется функция наследника?

Comment: @ArtGrek13 Да, всё именно так. Это называется полиморфизм - один из китов ООП.

Comment: Почитал о полиморфизме, спасибо!